# Manjaro Linux HDD Cloning/Backup to External Storage

Tags: linux, hard-disk, manjaro, external-hdd, cloning

I have Manjaro XFCE in my Laptop with Windows 8.1 in a dual-boot format.

Now, the **issue is** when Manjaro Linux is accessed, there is **a Continuous "Stroking"/"Screeching" Sound or Noise from the Internal Hard-drive**.

Now, some information about the Internal HDD of System-A:

- System-A: Dell Laptop Model: Inspiron 15.
- Seagate Standard Model Laptop Thin HDD;
- Model No.: ST500LT012-1DG142;
- Serial-ATA (SATA) interface
- 5400 RPM ; 6.0 GB/s, 500 GB

**What is the exact procedure of cloning an internal HDD to an external storage device in the Manjaro Linux environment? What I mean is the step-by-step instructions of using Linux command-line tool/terminal with a precise combination of flags for the particular command(s) to do the task.** Also, *some of the files/folders have very long Full PATH; So, while copying such data, the Linux command with an appropriate flag(s), should be able to transfer/copy it to an external device, without any interruption.*

**Also, what is the procedure of synchronizing cloned data in the external storage device with internal HDD/any new device?** By procedure, I mean, *is there any set of Linux commands that can smoothly perform the task of Periodic Synchronization, or, is there any separate 3rd-party tools for it?*

Alternatively, **is there any way to stop the screeching sound of the Internal HDD?** I tried using Linux Terminal Acoustics Management Tool, but, it says its not supported for this HDD.

Below is the output of the following command: **sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda**

```
/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       ST500LT012-1DG142                       
    Serial Number:      W3PE61T3
    Firmware Revision:  0001SDM1
    Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0029) 
    Supported: 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 8
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:   976773168
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:      476940 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:      500107 MBytes (500 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Form Factor: 2.5 inch
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5400
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
    Advanced power management level: 254
    Recommended acoustic management value: 208, current value: 0
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    NOP cmd
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Advanced Power Management feature set
            Power-Up In Standby feature set
       *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
            SET_MAX security extension
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
       *    64-bit World wide name
       *    IDLE_IMMEDIATE with UNLOAD
       *    Write-Read-Verify feature set
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Host-initiated interface power management
       *    Phy event counters
       *    Idle-Unload when NCQ is active
       *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
       *    Device-initiated interface power management
       *    Software settings preservation
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
       *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
            unknown 206[12] (vendor specific)
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    96min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 96min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5000c5007db7b2c6
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 000c50
    Unique ID   : 07db7b2c6
Checksum: correct
```

Below is the output of the following command: **sudo hdparm -M /dev/sda**

```
/dev/sda:
 acoustic      = not supported
```